# python pyautogui using multiple try catch is slow

Tags: python

```
                    try:
                        r = [pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('pgo.png', confidence=0.77,
                                                            region=(0, 0, 361, 514))[0],
                             pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('pgo.png', confidence=0.77,
                                                            region=(0, 0, 361, 514))[1]]
                    except Exception as e:
                        try:
                            r = [pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('pgo.png', confidence=0.77,
                                                                region=(0, 0, 361, 514))[0],
                                 pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('pgo.png', confidence=0.77,
                                                                region=(0, 0, 361, 514))[1]]
                        except Exception as e:
                            try:
                                r = [pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('pgo2.png', confidence=0.77,
                                                                    region=(0, 0, 361, 514))[0],
                                     pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('pgo2.png', confidence=0.77,
                                                                    region=(0, 0, 361, 514))[1]]
                            except Exception as e:
                                try:
                                    r = [
                                        pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('pgo.png', confidence=0.77,
                                                                       region=(0, 0, 361, 514))[0],
                                        pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('pgo3.png', confidence=0.77,
                                                                       region=(0, 0, 361, 514))[1]]
                                except Exception as e:
                                     pass
```

everthing work fine but the only problem is it take almost 4 to 6 sec to find an img , is there a way to search multiple img faster ?

Answer (score 0):

I think python itself is slower than any other languages like C, C++, Java etc.

You are using a library of python which is written in python (don't know exactly may be written in CPython, or any other) which makes it much slower.

One another issue can be **Retrieving depends on your system processing speed too**.

One solution can be **giving the absolute path of the image** from root or can be from the home directory.

Note: If pyautogui is searching all the directories and retrieving the image the above may work.